# using getBaseContext method

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a class which already inherits another class. Now from within this class, I want to start an activity, which needs activity class to be inherited. Which is not possible since my class has already inherited one.

In this situation, whats the best way to start an activity?
Some suggested me to use getBaseContext() method, but its saying "getBaseContext can not be resolved". Could anyone suggest a way...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a constructor for this class which takes Activity Instance as arguement.. and if u r creating object of this class in an activity.. pass its instance and then use that to get Context... or u can just say 
if its a reciever then its very easy.. reciever gets a context object in its **onRecieve** method.. which u can use like this

```
 Intent i = new Intent(context, some.class) //activity is an instance of Activity()
    i.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
   context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Can I create an instance of Activity class directly with statement,  Activity some = new Activity()...? I dont think its possible.

Comment: U may be allowed to do that but not use it any Where.. Only OS can create one for u,.. that too when u extend the class

Comment: If thats the case, how do you expect me to create an instance of Activity class and use in the statement, Intent i = new Intent(activity, some.class) //activity is an instance of Activity()...?

Comment: hey buddy.. I told you to take it from the Constructor.. if u can tell me u r program flow i can possible tell u..

Comment: Ya now i got wt u meant, but my class extends broadcast receiver, its a receiver, and so i cant create its instance and pass an activity instance to it as a parameter.